# iOS 9 Photos in on-phone album in random order: how to rearrange or sort?

Tags: ios, photos

I created a new album in my phone and added about 90 photos to it that I've taken over the past year -- all in-phone: no iTunes, no computer, no iPhoto... When I open that album, all the photos are in random order. Is there a way to sort the album by date? Or manually drag the photos to a new order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorting Manually** In an album that you made (not a smart album like Time Lapses or Selfies), to move a photo around: head into that album, press `Select` in the top-right, hold down on the photo you'd like to move, and drag it to the place you'd like to move it to.

**Sorting by date or name** In the Photos app on Mac, go into an album, press "View" in the menubar, hover over Sort, and choose to either sort by date or by name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is cool but it's still a pain to do manually... why do the photos show up in the album in random order?!

Comment: @pinhead I found a way to sort automatically, by date or by name. Check my answer. Note: you'll need a Mac, but it isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Select all pictures in the album using “select” and dragging across all pics. 
Use the “Add to” button at the bottom to add them all to a new album. 
The pictures will be in chronological order.

I hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

@ymcready That really helped!

The easiest way to reorder your album is to Click "Select" then "Select all"

Send to "Album"
"Create new Album" and create a new Album with a slightly different name.

Now the photos are in date order. Then delete original Album.

You will have to do this any time you add old photos.